# Distinct Rows in Sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, distinct-values

Below is my Query. This query is returning the following result set shown below in the image [image: Result Set]
But i want unique rows. How can i get unique rows?

```
Select
     distinct (tbl_Contract.ContractID),
     Tbl_Contract.KeyWinCountNumber,
     Tbl_Contract.ContractNumber,
     Tbl_Contract.ContractDate,
     Tbl_CountryFrom.CountryFromName,
     Tbl_CountryTo.CountryToName,
     tbl_Port.PortName,
     Tbl_Contract.Vans,
     Tbl_Contract.ContractID,
     Tbl_Item.ItemName,
     Tbl_Brand.BrandName,
     Tbl_Seller.SellerName,
     Tbl_Count.CountName,
     Tbl_Buyer.BuyerName

     from Tbl_Contract

     inner join Tbl_CountDetail
     on
     Tbl_CountDetail.ContractId = Tbl_Contract.ContractID
     inner join Tbl_Item
     on
     Tbl_Contract.ItemID = Tbl_Item.ItemID
     inner join Tbl_Brand
     on
     Tbl_Brand.BrandID = Tbl_Contract.ContractID
     inner join Tbl_Count
     on
     Tbl_CountDetail.CountId = Tbl_Count.CountID
     inner join Tbl_Seller 
     on
     Tbl_Seller.SellerID = Tbl_Contract.SellerID
     inner join Tbl_Buyer
     on
     Tbl_Buyer.BuyerID = Tbl_Contract.BuyerID
     inner join Tbl_CountryFrom
     on
     Tbl_CountryFrom.CountryFromID = Tbl_Contract.CountryFromID
     inner join Tbl_CountryTo
     on
     Tbl_CountryTo.CountryToID = Tbl_Contract.CountryToID
     inner join tbl_Port
     on
     tbl_Port.PortID = Tbl_Contract.PortID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distinct by `ContractId`?

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY ContractId` and select only the first of each group:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT C.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractId Order By ContractDate DESC)AS RN
    FROM Tbl_Contract C
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Note that you can add the joins in the cte without any problem. I've omitted them  for improved readability.

Comment: how can i add joins in it?

Comment: @AbidAli: The same way as always: `... FROM Tbl_Contract C INNER JOIN Tbl_CountDetail ON ...`.

Comment: can you please explain this query you have written?
what is With CTE and what does it does? and all the other keywords used in the query..

Comment: @AbidAli: A [**common table expression (CTE)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) can be thought of as a temporary result set (please read the link for further informations).  [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set with is defined through the `PARTITION BY` in the [`OVER`-clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx). The `Order By ContractDate DESC` defines how the group is ordered(change it accordingly).